# Creating a ConcurrentHashMap using defaults

Tags: java, collections

I created a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) using below. Which created `Segment` array with size `16`.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> c= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

However if I create the `CHM` using the below, it creates the `Segment` array with size `32`. Why is this the case when in both the cases effectively we are passing the same defaults?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> c= new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16,0.75f,16);
```

`Segment` is a `Static` inner class in `CHM` in `jdk7` and `jdk8` as below

```
static final class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable
```

Comment: What `Segment` array are you referring to?

Comment: @JacobG., The Segment array which gets create when you create a CHM

Comment: The only reference to `Segment` that I can find is in the source code documentation: `We also declare an unused "Segment" class that is instantiated in minimal form only when serializing.` - Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: @JacobG.Please go through the source code of CHM, it has static inner Class named Segment.

Comment: I already have; I'm running Java 14, so the source code may be different than what's contained in the version that you're using. The documentation of the `Segment` class in Java 14 states: `Stripped-down version of helper class used in previous version, declared for the sake of serialization compatibility.`, and it doesn't contain any array.

Comment: `Segment` has an array in Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_75), but starting with Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_181) it is no longer used, and has no array. In Java 7, `new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16,0.75f,16)` and `new ConcurrentHashMap<>()` is exactly the same thing, so your question is not making any sense. Why do you believe *"it creates the `Segment` array with size `32`"*, and in what version did you observe that, and how did you observe it?

Comment: @Andreas, I observe that it has size of 32 and 16 while debugging.

Comment: In what version did you observe that? I just tested this on **jdk1.7.0_75**, and **both** with and without parameters the `segments` field is an array of **size 16**. In **jdk1.8.0_181** there is **no `segments` field**.

Comment: You should note that your question is about implementation and source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave 16 as the initial capacity and the concurrency level, and 0.75 load factor. The Java 11 implementation uses the highest of the initial capacity and concurrency level as the initial capacity, in this case 16, and then divides by the load factor getting 21.333... and then rounds up to the nearest power of 2 getting 32.

Comment: Initial Capacity is the total number of key value pairs in the entire CHM? How can we calculate the size of the HashEntry[] within a particular Segment?

Comment: The initial capacity is just that, as one adds items to the map it may resize and increase its capacity according to a rather complex algorithm. The JavaDoc provides some explanation as to how it works.